# eclipse plugin import customized project

Tags: eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin, customization

I have an eclipse plugin which defines a customized project type. While creating files in the project, it creates also some extra files as "hidden resources". Everything works fine when I create a new project and add/remove files in it. The extra files are not shown in the project tree, just as I wished.

Now the problem is: if I remove this project from workspace, keep the content, and import it again using standard import, all the hidden resources are no longer hidden. Seems this "hidden" property of these files are gone, although I thought they should be stored somehow in the project folder.

So could anyone give me a hint if I need to implement a customized import to set the hidden resources hidden again? or what is missing? Couldn't find an answer with google. Honestly I don't even know if this is doable, because if I import a maven project, I can see the .project and .classpath are also shown, although they are hidden while creating a project.

Comment: Looks like the hidden flag is stored in the workspace .metadata directory as part of the 'ResourceInfo' data so it is not part of the project. Do you have a way to identify which files should be hidden without this information?

Comment: Thank you Greg, yes the hidden resources have their own file name extensions so I can identify them.

Comment: The normal Import Project wizard is `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.datatransfer.ExternalProjectImportWizard` however most of the things it uses are in internal classes making it hard to change.

Comment: yes when I use that it simply imports all files I created. And the decorations won't show either.

Comment: What I am saying is you will have to read the source of that and create a similar wizard doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case other people have the same question: this can be done with a IResourceChangeListener. E.g.

```
IResourceChangeListener listener = new MyResourceChangeReporter();
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener,IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE);
```